# what are you thinking about this car?

Tags: present-continuous

The norm is "What do you think about this car?"

But would it not make any sense to say:

"What are you thinking about this car?" to mean "what is that that you are thinking about my car?"

Answer (score 2):

They have slightly different implications, at least in US English.

**What do you think about this car?** means something like "What is your opinion of this car?" or "What do you think *in general* about this car?"  You might use this if you and your friend were looking at used cars together, and you pointed to one that you were thinking of buying.

**What are you thinking about this car?** means "What are you thinking *right now* about this car?", like "What thoughts are in your head at this moment about this car?"  This is a less common phrasing.  You might use it if you said to your friend, "I think am going to buy this car here," and they said, "Hm, OK, but..." and then stopped with a frown on their face.